# How to refresh the webview content (react-native app)?

Tags: android, ios, react-native, webview, expo

I have a react-native app (expo managed) and in this app I need to open a couple of webviews ( that are hosted on my website url). The issue is that when I update the content on the website, react-native webview still has the old website's content.

For example, react-native opens a webview page with a title **Library**, I've updated the title to **Libraries** and deployed the changes to my website, when I open the website (though phone/desktop) I see the title **Libraries**, but when I open the same page as the webview from the react-native app the title is still **Library**. If I delete and reinstall the react-native app then I see **Libraries**, I can't seem to figure out what may cause this issue.

This is my code:

```
import React, {useRef, useEffect} from 'react';
import { WebView } from 'react-native-webview';

const webViewRef = useRef();

useEffect(() => {
        
webViewRef.current.reload();

}, []);


WebView   
bounces={false}
ref={(ref) => (webViewRef.current = ref)}
source={{uri: "mywebsite"}}     
                
/>
```

Any advise or help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to fix this issue by passing a vavlue to the url,

```
import React, {useRef, useEffect,  **useState**} from 'react';
import { WebView } from 'react-native-webview';

const webViewRef = useRef();

**const [value, setValue] = useState()**

useEffect(() => {
        
webViewRef.current.reload();
*setValue(Math.random)*
}, []);


WebView   
bounces={false}
ref={(ref) => (webViewRef.current = ref)}
source={{uri: **`mywebsite?var=${value}`**}}
```

This allows webview url to refresh on page load